# MySQL query working on 5.0.10, but not on 5.1.73

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following code:

```
/// GENERATE SQL FOR LOGIN
$sql_login = "
    SELECT 

    users.id,
    users.email,  
    users.first_name, 
    users.last_name,  

        users.access_early_years,
        users.access_early_years_news,
        users.access_early_years_meetings,
        users.access_early_years_bpn,
        users.access_primary,
        users.access_primary_news,
        users.access_primary_meetings,
        users.access_primary_bpn,
        users.access_secondary,
        users.access_secondary_news,
        users.access_secondary_meetings,
        users.access_secondary_bpn,
        users.access_special,
        users.access_special_news,
        users.access_special_meetings,
        users.access_special_bpn,
        users.access_post_16,
        users.access_post_16_news,
        users.access_post_16_meetings,
        users.access_post_16_bpn,

    users.access_la_admin,
    users.last_login,
    users.login_count,
    users.centre_id,
    centres.name,
    centres.email AS centre_email,
    centres.active

    FROM users 

    INNER JOIN centres
    ON users.centre_id = centres.id

    WHERE 
    users.email = ? 
    AND 
    users.password = ? 
    LIMIT 1
";

echo $sql_login;

// PREPARE THE STATEMENT
$stmt_login = $conn->prepare($sql_login);
if($stmt_login === false) {
  trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $stmt_login . ' Error: ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR); 
  exit();
}

// BIND THE PARAMETERS... s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob */
$stmt_login->bind_param('ss',$username,$password);

// EXECUTE STATEMENT
$stmt_login->execute();

$stmt_login->bind_result(

    $user_id,
    $username,
    $first_name,
    $last_name,
        $access_early_years,
        $access_early_years_news,
        $access_early_years_meetings,
        $access_early_years_bpn,
        $access_primary,
        $access_primary_news,
        $access_primary_meetings,
        $access_primary_bpn,
        $access_secondary,
        $access_secondary_news,
        $access_secondary_meetings,
        $access_secondary_bpn,
        $access_special,
        $access_special_news,
        $access_special_meetings,
        $access_special_bpn,
        $access_post_16,
        $access_post_16_news,
        $access_post_16_meetings,
        $access_post_16_bpn,
    $access_la_admin,
    $last_login,
    $login_count,
    $centre_id,
    $centre_name,
    $centre_email,
    $centre_active



);


// SET THE SESSIONS AND LOG THE USER IN
while ($stmt_login->fetch()) {

// DO STUFF

}
```

Everything runs fine on PHP Version 5.4.24 with mysql 5.0.10 running an IIS server.

But, when transferring to PHP Version 5.5.14 with mysql 5.1.73 running plesk it does not.

It wont fetch any data.

This is replicated when querying the database with phpmyadmin with identical queries. One fetches the data, one doesn't. Both databases are direct copies of each-other.

I'm pulling my hair out! Any ideas?

**UPDATE: Tested with another prepared statement and everything went through fine (this statement was an UPDATE rather than a SELECT - so I can't see any issues with database user permission).**

Comment: The first thing to verify is that PHP isn't issuing any warnings or errors.  Always when developing/testing code `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of the script.

Comment: There's definitely nothing about the query that would break between 5.0/5.1.  You obviously cannot directly replicate the PHP code in PHPMyAdmin owing to the `?` placeholders.  Are you certain the connected user has the same access to both databases?

Comment: Debug also by removing the `WHERE` clause.  (This suggests passwords are being stored in plain text, which is deeply unsafe. Please review [How do you use bcrypt for password hashing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php) for options to improve, especially since you have PHP 5.5 at your disposal)

Comment: I am md5 storing the passwords currently.

Comment: I am not directly querying due to the prepared statement but have checked the variables (both identical on both servers) and replaced the ? when inputting into phpmyadmin

Comment: Oh sorry. And yes error reporting is set to E_ALL and Display_errors is 1

Comment: Does MySQL return any error message? Did you try a `mysqli_error()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. For some reason **INNER JOIN** didn't want to work on the newer version of mySQL, so I changed it to **LEFT JOIN** and all worked. I'm still confused as to why

Comment: That's not possible.... if is working with `LEFT` and not with `INNER` then the table `users` do not have any valid centre in table `centres`